# Solve ODE in tensorflow with tensor inputs

Tags: tensorflow2.0, ode, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to solve many instances of the same ODE across different constants.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

class SimpleODEModule(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        
    def __call__(self, t_initial, x_initial, solution_times, parameters):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            tape.watch(parameters)
            solution = tfp.math.ode.BDF().solve(
                                    self.ode_system, 
                                    t_initial,
                                    x_initial,
                                    solution_times,
                                    constants={'parameters': parameters})
            tape.gradient(solution.states, parameters)
        return solution.states
    
    def ode_system(self, t, x, parameters):
        a = parameters[:, 0]
        b = parameters[:, 1]
        dx = tf.add(tf.multiply(b, tf.exp(tf.multiply(a, t))), tf.multiply(a, x))
        print(dx)
        return dx

constants = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0],[3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]], dtype=tf.float32)
t_initial = tf.reshape(tf.cast(tf.repeat(0.0, constants.shape[0]), dtype=tf.float32), (1,constants.shape[0]))
x_initial = tf.reshape(tf.cast(tf.repeat(0.0, constants.shape[0]), dtype=tf.float32), (1,constants.shape[0]))
solution_times = tf.cast(tf.repeat(1.0, constants.shape[0]), dtype=tf.float32)

simple_ode = SimpleODEModule()

# This causes an error deep down int tfp.ode
# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
simple_ode(t_initial, x_initial, solution_times, constants)

# Returns the expected output x(1.0) for each set of constants
simple_ode.ode_system(t_initial, x_initial, constants)
```

I am new to tensorflow, so I imagine I am not creating the correctly shaped tensors somewhere. I would expect this to "just work", iterating over the dimensions of the tensors to solve the ODE multiple times for each set of constants. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Although I am not sure it is the best one. Instead of subclassing `tf.Module` I subclassed `tf.keras.layers.Layer` and it "just worked". Here is the change in the code:

```
class ODELayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs, ode_system):
        super(ODELayer, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs
        self.ode_system = ode_system

    def call(self, input_tensor):
        return tf.map_fn(self.solve_ode, input_tensor)
    
    def solve_ode(self, parameters):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            tape.watch(parameters)
            solution = tfp.math.ode.BDF().solve(
                    self.ode_system,
                    0.0, 0.0, [1.0],
                    constants={'parameters': parameters}
                )
            tape.gradient(solution.states, parameters)
        return solution.states
    
def simple_ode(t, x, parameters):
    a = parameters[0]
    b = parameters[1]
    dx = tf.add(tf.multiply(b, tf.exp(tf.multiply(a, t))), tf.multiply(a, x))
    return dx
```

Thanks to anyone who looked at this or attempted a solution.